# Can't display array to ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I can't display array to ionic view with NgFor

```
this.dbFire.database.ref('found').orderByChild('author_email').equalTo(this.email).once('value')
            .then(snapshot => snapshot.val())
            .then((data) => {
                // push data
                this.getUserPosts.push(data);
                console.log(this.getUserPosts);
            });

View:
    <ion-col  *ngFor="let posts of getUserPosts">
        <p>{{posts.post_name}}</p>
        <p></p>
    </ion-col>
```

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yS6g.jpg)

Comment: Please show us the output of `console.log(this.getUserPosts)`

Comment: Please see console.log anchor from post. There is the output of console.log(this.getUserPosts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the structure of `getUserPosts` you should be doing:
Add a new class member `postids` as an array of strings.Code Modifications as follows:

```
this.dbFire.database.ref('found').orderByChild('author_email').equalTo(this.email).once('value')
                .then(snapshot => 

snapshot.val())
            .then((data) => {
                // push data
                this.getUserPosts.push(data);
                console.log(this.getUserPosts);
    this.postids =  Object.keys(this.getUserPosts[0]);
    console.log(this.postids);
            });
```

View:

```
<ion-col  *ngFor="let postid of postids">
    <p>{{ getUserPosts[0][postid].post_name}}</p>
    <p></p>
</ion-col>
```

Comment: New error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

Thanks!

Comment: Please try again... Earlier I had typed Obeject.keys instead of Object.keys

Comment: Okay then, createa datamember with array<string> datatype named postids and use it... I will be updating the answer accordingly.

Comment: We need to store the keys in a separate array as Object.keys doesn't work inside ngFor.  Angular assume that Object here is a datamember of the class but since we don't have any datamember named Object it gives such error. Please try the updated code from the answer.

Comment: Works! Thank you!!

Comment: Please consider upvoting the answer as well.